# How to run specific test blocks e.g. SMOKE and REGRESSION test cases from multiple common spec in CYPRESS

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

We are using [CYPRESS](https://www.cypress.io/) tool for e2e test automation and loving it but we need run a specific set of tests(it or context blocks) in case of SMOKE(small set of tests) and REGRESSION(large set of tests).Lets take an example.

testsuite1.spec.js

```
context("usecase1", () => {
  it("testcase1", () => { // SMOKE + REGRESSION
    //some testcase1 checks
  });

  it("testcase2", () => { // REGRESSION
    //some testcase2 checks
  });
});
```

testsuite2.spec.js

```
context("usecase2", () => {
  it("testcase1", () => {  // SMOKE + REGRESSION
    //some testcase1 checks
  });

  it("testcase2", () => {  // SMOKE + REGRESSION
    //some testcase2 checks
  });

  context("usercase2.1", () => {
    it("testcase3", () => {  // REGRESSION
      //some testcase3 checks
    });
  });
});
```

Now in case of SMOKE we need to run -

testsuite1.spec.js:

- testcase1

testsuite2.spec.js:

- testcase1
- testcase2

And in case of REGRESSION we neeed to run -

testsuite1.spec.js:

- testcase1
- testcase2

testsuite2.spec.js:

- testcase1
- testcase2
- testcase3

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found out how to achieve this yet?

Answer (score 0):

u can Use it.skip for test case that u dont need to run

```
context("usecase1", () => {
  it("testcase1", () => { // SMOKE + REGRESSION
    //some testcase1 checks
  });

  it.skip("testcase2", () => { // REGRESSION
    //some testcase2 checks
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you modify dozens of tests each time a different subset must be run on CI?